# The difference between rand(1e9...1e10).to_i and rand.to_s[2..11].to_i

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, random, maxlength

In Ruby 2.3.0, when I do `rand.to_s[2..11].to_i` to insert something multiple times in a loop in the ActiveRecord, which validates `length: {maximum: 10, minimum: 10}`. I got an error after some iteration that the length validation failed! And when I do `rand(1e9...1e10).to_i` in the same scenario, it solves the problem. I want to know what's the difference between these two.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A string containing 10 random digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#rand` without arguments generates a random number between 0 and 1.

This can be `0.01111111111111`. `to_s[2..12]` then takes the first 10 digits after the decimal dot.

```
'01'.to_i # => 1
```

Hence you might get length less than 10.

Comment: @reznov9185: Note that this answer is half of the story, or let's say 99.999% of the story. For the rest, see the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`Kernel#rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) without an argument returns a pseudo-random [`Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html) in the interval [0.0, 1.0). So, it could return such values as `0.0`, or `0.123`, their string representation is less than 12 characters, so, if you take `"0.123"[2..11]` it returns `"123"`.

`rand(range)` returns a pseudo-random [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) in the given [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html), so `rand(1e9...1e10)` always returns a number which whole part has 10 digits.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue OP is experiencing: `10_000_000.times.map { rand.to_s[2..11] }.min_by(&:length).length # => 10`.

Comment: @ndn: I think you are both correct. `0`s could come from both sides of the string : 1 `0` is enough from the left, but 7 consecutive `0`s are needed from the right. So ndn's explanation is more probable, but MikDiet should play a role every 10 million rands.

Comment: @EricDuminil, makes sense.

Comment: @ndn: `100_000_000.times.map { rand.to_s }.min_by(&:length) #=> "0.684995671"` So it does happen sometimes.

Comment: @EricDuminil, you guys got lucky! (: Anyways, using `#to_i`, I got length 8 with just 100 numbers. One is significantly more likely though. But I do agree that both are possible and together they give the actual complete answer.

Comment: @ndn: Note that I use `100_000_000`. So there was a `1-(1-1E-7)**1E8` chance of getting at least one random number with 7 trailing `0`s. That's approximately `0.9999546` probability. I tried it again, and even got `"0.97585113"`

Comment: @EricDuminil, this assumes that all numbers with 16 digits after the decimal dot can be represented as float numbers, which is not the case. So the actual probability is slightly higher. (: